# List of arrays in array for google chart in C# MVC

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I have to create an array that contains list of arrays for google chart pie.

```
[['Status', 'Count'],['New',5], ['Converted',0],['Completed',0]]
```

One method I used which is quickest to implement but a bit dirty:

```
public class DashboardVM
{
    public DashboardVM(IEnumerable<Lead> leadsForOrganisation)
    {
        this.leadsByAgent = new List<LeadsByAgent>();
        this.leads = leadsForOrganisation;

        foreach (var groupedLeads in leadsForOrganisation.GroupBy(m=>m.contactId))
        {
            this.leadsByAgent.Add(new LeadsByAgent(groupedLeads));
        }

        string chart = "[['Status', 'Count'],['New'," + leadsForOrganisation.Where(m => m.leadStatusId == 1).Count() +
            "], ['Converted'," + leadsForOrganisation.Where(m => m.leadStatusId == 3).Count() +
            "],['Completed'," + leadsForOrganisation.Where(m => m.leadStatusId == 2).Count() + "]]";

        this.googleChartData = chart;

    }

    public List<LeadsByAgent> leadsByAgent { get; set; }
    public string googleChartData { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<Lead> leads { get; set; }


}
```

and on VIEW

```
        function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        @Html.Raw(Model.googleChartData )
        );

        var options = {
            title: '',
            is3D: true,
            backgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
            width:500,
            height:300,
          };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

The second method, cleaner but seems like might be overkill for this task.

```
 public class DashboardVM
 {
    public DashboardVM(IEnumerable<Lead> leadsForOrganisation)
    {
        this.leadsByAgent = new List<LeadsByAgent>();
        this.leads = leadsForOrganisation;

        foreach (var groupedLeads in leadsForOrganisation.GroupBy(m=>m.contactId))
        {
            this.leadsByAgent.Add(new LeadsByAgent(groupedLeads));
        }
    }

    public List<LeadsByAgent> leadsByAgent { get; set; }


    public string gchartJavaScriptJson { get { return getJsonChart(); } }
    public IEnumerable<Lead> leads { get; set; }

    public string getJsonChart()
    {
        var data = new object[] {
            new object[]{"Status", "Count"},
            new object[]{"New", this.leads.Where(m => m.leadStatusId == 1).Count()},
            new object[]{"Contacted", this.leads.Where(m => m.leadStatusId == 2).Count()},
            new object[]{"Converted", this.leads.Where(m => m.leadStatusId == 3).Count()}
        };

        return  new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data);
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
 function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
        @Html.Raw(Model.gchartJavaScriptJson)
        );

        var options = {
            title: '',
            is3D: true,
            backgroundColor: '#F9F9F9',
            width:500,
            height:300,
          };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Any ideas for better cleaner approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the first option looks clean enough for the purpose.

You could group the leads on status to get the count for each:

```
Dictionary<int, int> leadsByStatus =
  leadsForOrganisation.GroupBy(m => m.leadStatusId)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

You can use `String.Format` for a bit cleaner code when you put several values in a string:

```
string chart = String.Format(
  "[['Status', 'Count'],['New',{0}], ['Converted',{1}],['Completed',{2}]]",
  leadsByStatus[1], leadsByStatus[3], leadsByStatus[2]
);
```